# Call a function reference to a templated base class function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, reference, callback

I am struggling to understand why I cannot call a reference to a base class function. If you guys have some ideas please share them with me. More explanations in the code. This is just a representation of what I am trying to do since I am using boost and the code is way too long.

Live sample in rextester: http://rextester.com/live/QRJHPL54630

```
//g++  5.4.0

#include <iostream>

//have a base class which calls a function from the derived template
template<typename Derived>
struct Base
{
    template<void (Derived::*action)(void)>
    void callMethod(Derived& d)
    {
        (d.*action)();
    }
};

struct Evt
{
    void evt_doSmth(){ std::cout << "finally" << std::endl; };    
};


struct Foo : public Base<Foo>, public Evt
{
    void foo_doSmth(){ std::cout << "i expected this" << std::endl; };    
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;

    //this works because the function in declared in the Foo class
    f.callMethod<&Foo::foo_doSmth>(f);
    f.foo_doSmth();

    //i don't understand why this is not working, because the function
    //should be accessible from the Foo class since it inherits Evt class
    //could not convert template argument.

    f.callMethod<&Foo::evt_doSmth>(f);//<------- this does not work.

    f.evt_doSmth(); // works obviously
}
```

Comment: `could not convert template argument ‘&Evt::evt_doSmth’ to ‘void (Foo::*)()’` sounds pretty clear to me. `&Evt::evt_doSmth` is `void (Evt::*)()`, not `void (Foo::*)()`.

Comment: @Quentin yes I can see that too, but why Foo is not knowing about the evt_doSmth because Evt class is inherited by Foo

Comment: It's not a visibility issue, it's a type mismatch. You probably don't want to juggle member functions pointers here -- just accept a functor and pass in a lambda that calls the function on its argument.

Comment: If you are willing to be more explicit about the types you could use: http://cpp.sh/4e4mn

Comment: @Jonas unfortunately i cannot make changes in the Base class since it is part of a lib, boost lib